# Abandoned cart emails are not sending the second time

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am using Magento Enterprise 2.2.3 and am experiencing an issue in the abandoned cart functionality. I have set an abandoned cart email without setting the number of days and without any other conditions. I am getting the customer listed in matched customers section the first time he abandons the cart and the email is being sent. The second time the user abandons the cart, the matching customers list is not updated and hence email is not sent.

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that should have been patched -- try updating the software.

Comment: Any idea the version in which this issue was fixed ? I am using enterprise 2.2.3 now.